# Can I re apply for a tourist visa immediately

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino citizen and I applied for a family visitor visa. The main reason for me to go to UK is to accompany my niece who is a minor in traveling to UK, however my visa was denied. The grounds they told me regarding the refusal is that the exact date as to when will I be going back to the Philippines. Another one is that they are not convinced whether the mother of my niece is indeed my cousin or a sibling when I presented them the red ribboned birth certificate. Also, they told me that  since I am currently unemployed, then I cannot finance my travel expenses.

This is very vague since my cousin will be sponsoring me because it is their daughter whom I will accompany to travel. I presented them her pay slip, remittances, bank statements, tax declaration, house tenancy contracts and bills, but still they are looking for proofs. Can you please help me to answer these grounds.thank you.

Comment: They would have sent you a refusal notice; please edit your question to copy its text so that we have the exact wording of your refusal.  For UK visit refusals it's important to see the formulae they used. See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51842/refused-uk-visit-visa-for-lack-of-sufficient-funds-what-more-can-i-do) for an example. Close voting this question as 'unclear' until it's edited.  Thanks.