# Uk visa Refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I am a Ghanian citizen.

The evidence I provided in support of my UK visa application is: a letter from my employer, wage slips from my company, bank statements, the person who invited me provided his utility bills, invitation letter, and a bank statement.

The refusal is  as follows:

> Firstly, on your application form, you stated that you wish to visit your friend and they will maintain and accommodate you. I have recognized the importance of family visits and have carefully considered your application; however, the documents that you have presented to me do not establish that your sponsor is able to undertake such responsibility.
>
> For example, you have failed to provide sufficient satisfactory evidence of adequate accommodation available to you. Furthermore, you have also failed to provide satisfactory evidence of sponsor income, employment or financial and personal commitment.  Given the above, I am not satisfied that you will be adequately maintained and accommodated in the United Kingdom or that you can meet the cost of your return or onward journey.
>
> The Second reason is that you have stated that you spend xxx per month on a living cost living costs and supporting your family leaving you with a disposable income of xxx.  You stated that the cost to you personally of your visit is xxx.  This amount is 7 times your monthly income once family and living costs have been deducted and I am not satisfied this is credible considering your personal and financial circumstances.
>
> Lastly in light of all of the above I am not satisfied as to your intentions in wishing to travel to the United Kingdom and will leave the UK at the end of your visit.  Furthermore, I am not satisfied that you have sufficient funds available to cover your costs whilst in the UK without working or accessing public funds.  your application for a visit visa has been refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) (e).

How can I re-apply for a visa?

Comment: Nationality? Full text of refusal? What evidence did you provide? What's the nature of your trip?

Comment: They would have sent you a refusal notice; please edit your question to copy its text so that we have the exact wording of your refusal.  For UK visit refusals it's important to see the formulae they used. See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51842/refused-uk-visit-visa-for-lack-of-sufficient-funds-what-more-can-i-do) for an example. Close voting this question as 'unclear' until it's edited.  Thanks.

Comment: please my question was put on hold because of duplicate. i sent it again because i did not know how to edit it.so i taught sending the same question again will be the best.thank you

Answer (score 2):

If we reconstruct the ECO's logic...

You have have a friend in the UK who wants to sponsor you for a visit.  Your friend's evidence was so light and missing so many pieces that the ECO discounted it as unacceptable (letting that happen was a mistake).  So the only evidence left for the ECO to consider was your evidence, which he duly considered and concluded that a trip to the UK on your income was disproportionate (V 4.2 (e)).  He doubts your friend's sincerity and thinks you will try to go underground in the UK  (V 4.2 (a)).  He was lenient because he could have thrown 4.2 (c) in for icing on the cake, but did not.

This sort of thing will happen when a person cannot afford to travel from their own resources and relies upon a sponsor who does not provide what they need to see.  It also happens when the ECO doesn't understand why a sponsor is offering to sponsor somebody.

You can make a fresh application, but it's advisable to have your friend download and read [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) about what they want to see.  Your friend needs to send on your behalf everything that a bona fide applicant would send.  If you are planning to use your friend's place for accommodation, they should additionally include a landlord's consent (or the relevant text in the tenancy agreement).

For some reason Ghanaian applicants always seem to start with two strikes so your next application should reflect diligence. If there's an evidential shortfall, it's best to wait and apply at a more promising time.

Comment: Please thank you very much. my friend is ready to send all needed documents but please what should i do in regards to the second reason if i want to make a new application. thank you

Comment: @Princessportia if your friend is carrying the application then you should focus on social standing, family, employment etc etc

Comment: thank you very much..but i didn't quiet get this answer . Please kindly explain further.am confuse please.thank you

Comment: @Princessportia we really don't need 'thanks' or comment digressions, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers before commenting again