# Have you previously applied to enter or remain in Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, international-travel, planning, working-holiday

I have had a working holiday visa before and I am applying again, do I say yes to this question or no. I have to explain if I say yes

Comment: Why would you say no...?

Comment: Canadian officials aren't stupid. They keep computerized records of these things. If you give a false answer, they'll know and then you're credibility with them will be shot.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has so many upvotes.

Comment: Just yesterday there was this example of what happens when you "forget" to tick the right box on your visa application (it's about the UK, but I expect the basic rules to be the same for Canada): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72528/reason-for-a-uk-visa-refusal. TL;DR: Lie and you won't get in for a long time.

Comment: @ZachLipton Seeing the second part of your comment on a quick glance, all I could see was "you will be shot". Your and you're matters.

Comment: I'm quite sure this question has so many views because everyone wanted to check out if someone is actually using SE question to make a poll.

Comment: @TomášZato hah! That's what I get for commenting when I should be sleeping

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you have applied to enter Canada before.

Comment: do I explain why I left and why I am applying again?

Comment: @tia yes.  If you want them to let you in the country again, you should answer their questions truthfully.  Government officers generally don't like it when people lie to them.

Comment: *"do I explain why I left and why I am applying again?"* If and only if they ask.

Comment: @fkraiem typically when you answer a question like this in the affirmative, you are faced with a prompt such as "if yes, please provide details."

Comment: @phoog In this case I would just say "Applied for working holiday visa on XX/XX/XX."