# Rejection of UK visa got an entire delegation coming for University-sponsored one-week training

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

Recently, UK visit visa of entire delegation comprising of 15 full time faculty members of our university based in Pakistan and ranked top most in private sector universities has been rejected.

The reasons for refusal are astonishing. Almost all of us had different reasons for refusal through we provided same documents and were going for a one week academic training.

One reason is that the refusal letter states we had not provided any proof that we will be back after the training is over though we had attached travel reservations and the facilitation letter offered by university also clearly mentioning the dates of the start and end of training.

Is there any other document required to provide an evidence that the i will be back on very next day the training is over?

Secondly, the refusal letter states that i have not mentioned what i will do other than the 20 hours of tuition in the training session. How do i provide an evidence that my sole purpose is attending the training session and i have no other business there?

We are left with 15 days now for the training to start. Could you highlight the issues in our applications? will it prove good to re apply at this point of time?

Comment: Well right off the top, did you provide any paycheck stubs to show that you were paid or just a letter "from the University"?  Did the amount of money being deposited into your accounts correspond to your stated salary (plus maybe earnings from your spouse)?  Or were you folks padding your accounts with extra cash to make your financial wherewithal look better?  Big deposits prior to applying for a visa is a big red flag.

Comment: The letter mentioned that travel, accommodation and tuition fee would be provided by the university. It was signed by the rector of the university. Yes my stated salary corresponded with my bank statement. Huge transactions were done for various personal reasons and no extra cash was added almost 2 months prior. Do you have any idea about rest of the reasons mentioned?

Comment: Did you show you have reason to return to Pakistan after the event? Did you explain why there were suspicious looking transactions in your account? Have you read any of the other UK Visa Refusal questions we have here?

Comment: That's too many reasons for one applicant.  They would have sent you a refusal notice; please edit your question to copy its text so that we have the exact wording of your refusal.  For UK visit refusals it's important to see the formulae they used. See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51842/refused-uk-visit-visa-for-lack-of-sufficient-funds-what-more-can-i-do) for an example. Close voting this question as 'unclear' until it's edited.  Thanks.