# Is immediate reapplication fruitful for UK business visit with more documents as evidence?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, business-travel

Our university delegation comprising of 15 female faculty members of English have been invited to attend a 7 day training session of English Language Teaching Methodology in **redacted** University UK. Every year a delegate visits this university to get the training. However, this year the visas of all of us have been refused. My visa has been refused due to following reasons:

> 1- In order to assess your intentions i must consider your
>   circumstances in Pakistan based on the information you have provided
>   with application. All applicants are advised to substantiate their
>   circumstances. We expect applicants to provide this information as it
>   assists us in making an informed assessment as to whether they intend
>   to comply with the terms of visitor entry clearance.
>
> 2- You state you intend to visit UK to attend Language Teaching
>   Methodology and British Culture and Society training and have
>   submitted a letter from **redacted** university UK confirming that you
>   have been invited to attend the training. The documents that you have
>   submitted do not show any professional requirement for you to attend
>   this course however and it is not clear why you wish to take part in
>   this course.  3- You state that you intend to visit UK for 7 days and
>   the contact time for the course in **redacted** university UK is 20
>   hours. The documents that you have provided do not demonstrate what
>   else you intend to do with your stay in the UK. I am not satisfied
>   with your intentions as stated.
>
> 4- You state that your employer **redacted** University Pakistan will
>   pay all costs for your proposed trip and you have submitted a letter
>   from them confirming that they will pay for your expenses including
>   your flight, boarding and lodging. The documents that you have
>   provided do not demonstrate that your employer has the required funds
>   therefore i am not satisfied that they can provide support to you for
>   your intended visit. Your application is refused under paragraph V 4.3
>   of immigration rules.
>
> 5-I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor
>   and you intend to leave UK at the end of your visit. Your application
>   is refused under paragraph V 4.2 a and c of the immigration rules.

What kind documents do i provide to state I will be back to Pakistan the very next day the training is over? I did provide flight details and do not have any property here in Pakistan and am unmarried.

I do not wish to take part in any other activity other than the said training. How do i prove that?

How do i prove that my university has sufficient funds. It is so obvious that the university has funds as it is one of the leading universities of Pakistan. Moreover, they provided a letter stating they are providing and supporting me financially. What else is required on part of the university?

I am English Lecturer (teaching language to undergraduates)- mentioned on letter issued by university where i am working. How else do i demonstrate my professional requirement for the course?

The training is scheduled for 24 of this month. Do you think i can re apply with more documents as evidence? What chances do i have to attaining the visa within these days?

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Instead, [edit your existing question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57277/rejection-of-uk-visa-got-an-entire-delegation-coming-for-university-sponsored-on).

Comment: They would have sent you a refusal notice; please edit your question to copy its text so that we have the exact wording of your refusal.  For UK visit refusals it's important to see the formulae they used. See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51842/refused-uk-visit-visa-for-lack-of-sufficient-funds-what-more-can-i-do) for an example. Close voting this question as 'unclear' until it's edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Why would a university's credibility be challenged?  Well, reading the refusal notice, the question that jumps to mind is...  Has the university sponsored visitors in the past who have abused their visas?  When this happens, the sponsor loses credibility and will find it difficult to sponsor people in the future. Of course this is not your fault and possibly not even the university's fault, but if the university has stepped forward in the past to sponsor someone and the person absconded or in some other way engaged in abuse, and there is a clear pattern associated with it, then yes, the decision-maker will take this in to account.  I emphatically repeat: they would need a *clear pattern* before taking a step like this (and apparently they have one).

Secondarily, the university proposes to send 15 female delegates for a period of 7 days to take a 20 hour course that isn't part of the curriculum.  Not very believable is it?  The combined air fare and lodging alone amounts to what? GBP 30,000?  Where does a university find that kind of money? At that rate the university could hire the instructor for a week to teach a localised version of the course in Pakistan and still save money.  Criminey, for 30k, even I would go for a week  and teach it.

They refused for several reasons, the primary hit was on V4.3, namely they do not trust the university that is sponsoring you.  I don't think sending more documents is going to fix the problems here, and I would suggest deferring your next application until a believable premise and reliable sponsorship can be found. The university should find out why and where the credibility problems arose and fix them; they should instruct legal counsel in the UK to provide representation if comparable resources do not exist in Pakistan.

Comment: Does that mean we cannot apply for this training from university's platform again? People from our university do visit another top ranked UK university as we have degree partnership with it. How do you see this?

Comment: That may be the source of the problem. But please read the part about " they should instruct legal counsel" again.

Comment: Right what about rest of the reasons?

Comment: Fix the big hit and then ask a new question.